# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate not updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

So, I've been working with MongoDB for a couple days, I have been doing a per-server mute role command but when I was doing the **set muterole** command, when using **findOneAndUpdate** function, it doesn't seem to update the values, I've been searching for other answers and I've tried multiple of them, yet it doesn't seem to work, this is my code:

```
muteSchema.findOne(
                {
                    guildId: message.guild.id
                }, async (err, data) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err)
                    if(data)
                    {
                        muteSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
                            {
                                guildId: data.guildId
                            },
                            {
                                guildId: message.guild.id,
                                roleId: role.id
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = new muteSchema(
                            {
                                guildId: message.guild.id,
                                roleId: role.id
                            }
                        )
   
                        data.save().catch((err) => console.log(err) )
                    }
                }
            )
```

I do have the **muteSchema** import on top and this is my muteSchema file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

let MuteroleSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        guildId: String,
        roleId: String
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("muterole", MuteroleSchema)
```

The values are registered the first time it is used, but they don't update once they are there.

Answer (score 1):

You are making things too complex for yourself. Why do you first find then again find and then update?
Simply go with the following flow

```
Update using filter
```

Code Sample:

```js
exports.updateToken = async (id, forgotToken) => {//function
return User.updateOne({ _id: id }, { resetPasswordToken: forgotToken });//_id:id is a filter while the reset is code to update 
}
```